# Dataframe merging - left join by matching more than 1 column (multiple column matching)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a main DF1 like this

| Name | Type | Price | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product A | Phone | 100 | 5 |
| Product B | TV | 30 | 3 |

DF2

| Name | Type | Image | Shelf Position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product A | Phone | image1 | Shelf A |
| Product A | TV | image 2 | Shelf B |
| Product A | Speakers | image 3 | Shelf C |
| Product B | Fridge | image 4 | Shelf A |
| Product B | TV | image 5 | Shelf F |

bI'm wondering if there is a neat solution to create a DF by LEFT JOIN DF2 with DF1 while matching by more than 1 column (in this case, the match will be on Name and Type)

| Name | Type | Price | Quantity | Image | Shelf Position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product A | Phone | 100 | 5 | image1 | Shelf A |
| Product B | TV | 30 | 3 | image 5 | Shelf F |

I was going to create a new combined column (name_type) and rely on it to left join but  I'm hoping to find out if there is a better way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `on` parameter of [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) accepts `lists`.

> on: label or **list**
> Column or index level names to join on. These must be
> found in both DataFrames. If on is None and not merging on indexes
> then this defaults to the intersection of the columns in both
> DataFrames.

```
out = df1.merge(df2, on=["Name", "Type"], how="left")
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)
        Name   Type  Price  Quantity    Image Shelf Position
0  Product A  Phone    100         5   image1        Shelf A
1  Product B     TV     30         3  image 5        Shelf F
```